# Webots - How mark coordinates in environment during simulation

Tags: webots

Robot controller uses RRT to generate a set of nodes (x,y) taking it from start to finish. If possible I would like for these nodes to somehow show in the environment.

**Edit:**

```
root = supervisor.getRoot() 
root_children_field = root.getField("children") root_children_field.importMFNode(-1,"tree_node.wbo") 
node = root_children_field.getMFNode(-1) 
field = node.getField("translation") 
location = [-1, 0.5, 0] # location of path node 
field.setSFVec3f(location)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Supervisor to import/modify/change/move/remove nodes (such as visual nodes) at runtime in the environment:
https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor

You will find some example simulations using the Supervisor here:

- https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/samples-devices#supervisor-wbt
- https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/samples-howto#supervisor_draw_trail-wbt

Comment: Thank you! I decided on importing and placing nodes at the coordinates I wanted to mark (shown in edit of OP). However, when I want to remove that node by just adding 

root_children_field2.removeMF(-1)

Webots freezes (not responding). Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have there same behaviour if you use Node.remove() instead (https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor?tab-language=python#wb_supervisor_node_remove) ?

Comment: I might've made a big mistake by not putting the remove line in the while loop. First it was in the beginning where everything is initialized, using Node.remove() here caused Webots to freeze as well. Using Node.remove() in the loop worked for me and I guess using root_children_field2.removeMF(-1) there would work too. Thanks for your help!